# What can go wrong if I use MD5 instead of SHA256 for the sake of file names?

Tags: hash, md5, sha

I'm developing a cache system. This system creates cache files for each API call.

Each API has a URL of course, and I'm using that URL to create a hash and use that hash as the name of the file.

The reason I can't use the URL directly as the name of the file is because many URLs contain Unicode characters and when they are URL encoded, they become very long and OS won't let me save them.

Now, I just tested some hashing algorithms online and it seems that MD5 generates shorter digests for me than SHA256.

So I want to use MD5. But do I lose anything? I mean, does it have any shortcomings that I might not see now?

Is there a greater chance for it to generate duplicate digests for different URLs?

Comment: How many cache files are we talking about here?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk                          
 It is not exactly clear because for each url in the api, I want to create a file, and with a slight change in the parameters of the new file, it should create maybe more than a thousand

Comment: In that case MD5 is more than adequate, even overkill. There is an extremely tiny, almost infinitesimal, chance of a collision.